Odata V2 Create (Virtual) Entry for Table
I have an empty SAPUI5 SmartTable (for Sales Order Items) and there I want to add new single (virtual) row where the user can input some Sales Order Item data, e.g. Material No., Price, Quantity ...
My problem now is the following:
This new row should not automatically be processed from the backend. For my understanding this documentation would be the correct approach to do that.
Am I right?
My OData Service is version 2, and we are on SAP UI Version 1.71.58. Within this version the ODataListBinding#create function is not released.
Am I also right here?
I've tried to solve my problem via the ODataModel#createEntry function, but this isn't working for tables. Is this also correct?
The ODataModel#createEntry is working fine for my header data Smart Field.
What can i do in this case?
What would be the best way to solve my problem?
Further Information:
I need the SmartTable and the OData Model for some automatic search help dialogs via annotations.

If you need to create virtual rows, use a JSON model instead of an OData model to bind with your table.
You can do the following:

read your data from a backend using OData;
put this data in the JSON model;
bind the JSON model to your table;
add an empty row to a JSON model manually when needed;
save data to the backend using the create method of OData.


Thx @shahhmatist for your answer.
I know about that possibility with Json and have done this in one of my older apps. My question or rather my wish for a Odata possibility is coming from that point of view that i want to use the annotation comfort functions within my table, f.e. the automatich search help dialog creation and so on ...
Is this annotation thing somehow also possible with a Json Model?
